# Javascript (Vue.js) - Adding Table Rows to the Wrong Node in the DOM

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I'm trying to create an initiative tracker for 5th Edition Dungeons and Dragons. Using the fetch function included in Vue, I have been able to obtain a list of all of the freely available monsters from the game and render them into an unordered list. I have added an `onclick` event to each item in the list so that when a name is clicked, a new instance of the monster object is added into the initiative table automatically after being appended to the `initiativeOrder` variable, but I'm noticing some anomalous behavior.

First of all, clicking a name in the list causes the new table row to appear outside of the table in regards to the DOM. Second, if you click the same name more than once, it doesn't add another row with the same information inside the table, which is what I expected.

How can I alter the markup and scripting so that every time I click an item in the list, a new item always appears at the appropriate location in the table?

```html
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en-GB">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Final Year Project | Battle Tracker for 5th Edition Dungeons and Dragons</title>
        <meta name="description" content="A Battle Tracker for 5th edition Dungeons and Dragons written using Progressive Web Technologies.">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <link rel="manifest" href="site.webmanifest">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icon.png">
        <!-- Place favicon.ico in the root directory -->

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/boilerplate.css">

        <meta name="theme-color" content="#160a0b">
    </head>

    <body>
        <!--[if IE]>
        <p class="browserupgrade">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="https://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience and security.</p>
        <![endif]-->

        <main id="app">
            <div class="sidebar">
                <nav id="commands">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <button type="button">Begin Encounter</button>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
            <div id="library">
                <ul>
                    <creature-listing
                    v-for="(index, creature) in creatures"
                    v-bind:creature="creature"
                    v-on:click="addCreature(index)"></creature-listing>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="initiative">
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Initiative</th>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Hit Points</th>
                            <th>Armor Class</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <combatant
                        v-for="combatant in initiativeOrder"
                        v-bind:combatant="combatant">
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </main>

        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.18/vue.min.js"></script>
        <!-- <script src="serviceworker.js"></script> -->
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

```js
Vue.component(
    'creature-listing',
    {
        props: [
            'creature'
        ],
        template: '<li>{{ index }} {{ creature.name }}</li>'
    }
);

Vue.component(
    'combatant',
    {
        props: [
            'combatant'
        ],
        template: `
            <tr>
                <td>?</td>
                <td>{{ combatant.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ combatant.hit_points }}</td>
                <td>{{ combatant.armor_class }}</td>
            </tr>
        `
    }
)

var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        creatures: [],
        initiativeOrder: []
    },
    methods: {
        addCreature: function (index) {
            this.initiativeOrder.push(this.creatures[index]);
        }
    },
    created: function () {
        // this runs when the component is mounted
        fetch("creatures.json")
            .then(data => data.json())
            .then(creatures => { this.creatures = creatures })
    }
});
```

Comment: you should have a `:key` for you `v-for`, maybe add `v-for=(combatant, i)... :key="i"`

Comment: I have changed the `<combatant>` component instance in the HTML to look like this:
```html
<combatant
v-for="(combatant, i) in initiativeOrder"
:key="i"
v-bind:combatant="combatant">
```
But that makes it even worse. The rows still show up in the wrong place and they don't show any information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is custom `tr` component. Table expects only `tbody`,`thead`,`tr`,`td`,`th` elements, so other elements instead of expected ones belongs not to table. You must place the whole table in your component.

This issue is related with any virtual node framework like angular, not only vue.

Example:

```js
new Vue({
  data: {
    rows:["row1", "row2"]
  },
  components: {
    myrows: {
      props: ['row'],
      template:'<tr><td>{{row}}</td></tr>',
    },
    mytable: {
      props: ['rows'],
      template:'<table><tr><td>TEST</td></tr><tr v-for="row in rows"><td>{{row}}</td></tr></table>',
    }
  }
}).$mount('div')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <table style='border:2px solid blue'><tr><td>TEST</td></tr><myrows v-for='row in rows' :row='row'></myrows></table>
  <mytable style='border:2px solid red' :rows='rows'></mytable>
</div>
```

You must provide the whole table in component. Your code must look like this:

```js
new Vue({
  data: {
    creatures: [
      {name:"Bat", hit_points: 200, armor_class: 5},
      {name:"Org", hit_points: 250, armor_class: 25}
    ]
  },
  components: {
    creatures: {
      props: ['data'],
      template: `<table> 
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Initiative</th>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Hit Points</th>
                            <th>Armor Class</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr v-for='combatant in data'>
                            <td>?</td>
                            <td>{{ combatant.name }}</td>
                            <td>{{ combatant.hit_points }}</td>
                            <td>{{ combatant.armor_class }}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>`
    }
  }
}).$mount('div')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="initiative">
  <creatures :data="creatures"></creatures>
</div>
```

Comment: "Table expects only tbody,thead,tr,td,th elements, so other elements instead of expected ones belongs not to the table". Do you mean to say that I can't add a regular table to the `index.html` file and then use a custom tag to fill in the rows?

Comment: Also, I've tried inserting this solution into my own code and it doesn't work as expected. What's it trying to demonstrate?

Comment: Tables works as you see only `<table><tbody><myrow>...` will not work

Comment: Updated answer with your data

Comment: Thank you for the clarifcation. This should help me a lot in building my application.

Comment: UPDATE: I was able to implement this solution rather successfully, but it's still not rendering duplicate list items. I'll have to change the name of creatures in the list anyway, so I'll probably end up doing that.